# Document_root server on 000webhost

Tags: php, document-root

So I have a server on 000webhost and I don't really know how to get to the public_html folder via php.

```
$abc = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/public_html/plik.txt",'a+');
```

any ideas how to get to that direction?

Comment: $abc = fopen('http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . '/pss.txt', 'ab');
if(!$abc)
{echo "<br /><br />Zamowienie Panstwa nie moze zostac przyjete w tej chwili. Prosze sprobowac pozniej.";}
$ciagwyjsciowy = $CPU."\t".$Cenazamowienia_netto."\t".$Cenazamowienia_brutto."\n";
fwrite($abc, $ciagwyjsciowy);
fclose($abc);

It doesn't throw any error now whatsoever though it doesn't create the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$abc = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/plik.txt", 'a+');
```

**UPDATE:**

For **removing** `open_basedir restriction` place this line in Apache server config:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/public_html>
   php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

Comment: that's not the case I have on top of the code $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Comment: What exactly is your full path for `plik.txt`?

Comment: ok so I can only upload files to public_html folder on this server and it doesn't matter for now where I want it just to work but I don't know the full path to the public_html folder.

Comment: I did **Edit** Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/public_html/plik.txt) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/a6907098/public_html/Sklep/process.php on line 24

Comment: I know I want to create it with this statement.

Comment: after adding this to htaaccess my site went down error404 so I had to delete It :/

Comment: I realized that `php_admin_value` line isn't allowed in .htaccess, see update above. This is needed in Apache config.

Comment: I have no idea how to access Apache config whatsoever.

Comment: Unfortunately to resolve this error, you will have to edit your server's `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get to the **public_html folder**, then go to the file and **click view**. The url above should do it for you. It should look like:

```
$abc = fopen("https://my-name.000webhostapp.com/plik.txt",'a+');
```

A different method would be required to get to the ***tmp*** *folder*.